# What causes 'Permission denied' error when trying to capture video in Ionic 6 + Angular 14 using MediaCapture plugin?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, video, capacitor

I am having trouble capturing video on a mobile application built with Ionic 6, Angular 14 and Capacitor 4.

Background:
I am trying to integrate with a 3rd party SDK that requires video permissions in order to complete a KYC process. Upon seeing that I get browser incompatibility errors when getting to the step where I am prompted to record a video, I tried to see if recording a video by other means is possible. It seems that with our current setup, it isn't.

I tried using the [MediaCapture](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/media-capture)  plugin as follows:

```
import { MediaCapture, CaptureVideoOptions } from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture/ngx";

// ...

async startRecording(): Promise<void> {
    const mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
    try {
      const opt: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1 };
      const data = await mediaCapture.captureVideo(opt);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e, "video capture error");
    }
  }

// ...
```

Note that I also need to instantiate MediaCapture, even though the official documentation asks to use DI to inject it like a service in the constructor. However, if I try that, my component won't even get initialized, as discovered when debugging and noticing that it wouldn't even enter `ngOnInit()`.

I have also tried using the [AndroidPermissions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/android-permissions) plugin for starters, just to make sure that there aren't any permissions missing:

```
await AndroidPermissions.requestPermissions([
      AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA,
      AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO,
      AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ]);
```

These are also included in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

From the documentation it is my understanding that these are the only permissions needed on Android. However, when I try to run this code, I reach the `catch` part of my `try/catch` block, where I get the following error object:

```
{code: 4, message: 'Permission denied.'}
```

This is very generic and doesn't reveal any useful info, I know.
I've been digging and found [this article](https://masteringionic.com/blog/resolving-android-eacces-error-when-building-ionic-apps-on-a-mac-system) about what the **4** could mean, but it wasn't of much use. I have been digging for hours looking for an answer, but haven't found anything too helpful. One article (can't find the url at the moment) stated that the error codes corresponding to one of the permissions above have different values (20, 70, something like that), but not 4. I have no idea what 4 means, and what needs to be done in order to stop receiving it.

I have tried various plugins previously, trying to simply record a video within the app, but none of them worked. Again, the end goal is not for my code to trigger the recording, but rather the 3rd party SDK, but in order for that to happen, I guess I need to figure our what that denied permission means.
I have also tried adding all the available permissions manually to the app from the Applications section in Android. I am testing on a Samsung S22 Ultra, and have been also doing some tests on an iPhone SE with iOS 16.4.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: using this plugin fork would fix the issue specifically for the media-capture plugin, but not generally for the app that tries to record videos by other means/plugins (in my case via the 3rd party sdk):

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/commit/d77d1715e5efbb29520169af27d3bf1a389115b4

So I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Update 2:
Using the AndroidPermissions plugin I noticed that I have two permissions missing:
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I explicitly request permissions for these, as originaly described in my post, but afterwards I try to get the permission status:
`await AndroidPermissions.checkPermission(AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);`

This is still false. I am assuming this is related to my issue.

Comment: Note that once you upgrade to Capacitor v5, this uses Android 13 SDK which introduces new media permissions which you'll need to handle on Android 13+ - [see here](https://github.com/capacitor-community/media/issues/49)

Comment: Thank you. I have just been reading about the deprecation of the permissions I mentioned. However, I am still on Capacitor 4 at the moment (even though targeting API 33).

Comment: @AndreiOltean Thank you very much, I was struggling with this one. For those who don't know how to install a specific commit, put this in your package.json file

```"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git#d77d1715e5efbb29520169af27d3bf1a389115b4"```